# Django: ValueError: too many values to unpack on User model

Tags: python, django

Here is what I'm trying

```
kwargs = {}

kwargs['username'] = 'abc'
kwargs['password'] = 'abc'
user = User.objects.get(*kwargs)
```

But it shows the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
```

Notice the extra `*`